# Surrounded by nature / in nature

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Which of the two options is more idiomatic? Are they both correct?

We're going camping because we want to spend some time surrounded by nature / in nature.

Answer (score 1):

"Surrounded by"  and not "surrounded in".  You could say "spend time in nature", but it's not particularly idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply James. Yes, I meant surrounded by nature or in nature. So, if I correctly understood what you wrote, "we're going camping because we want to spend some time surrounded by nature" is the best way to express this sentence. Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: As a native English speaker, if you said you were "surrounded in nature", I would think that you were out in some natural environment, and you were surrounded, but I would not know what you were surrounded by. I would not think you just meant the natural environment; I would think some people (or animals, or other such) had surrounded you, and this happened in a natural environment.